# Mac ignores Headphones after sleep

Tags: audio, sleep-wake, headphones, macos

The problem is that the Mac ignores the connected 3.5 headphones after sleep, but this does not apply to Bluetooth. With bluetooth headphones everything is fine.

I have already try to reset P/NVRAM.

Here is `dmesg`:

```
    ng poll type 4
Command 0x1100 completed. inCount: 2 data:0x0Failed to read key     . rc:0x84
Failed to read key     . rc:0x84
Failed to read key     . rc:0x84
Failed to read key     . rc:0x84
Failed to read key     . rc:0x84
Command 0x1200 completed. inCount: 2 data:0x0Failed to read key     . rc:0x84
Failed to read key     . rc:0x84
Failed to read key     . rc:0x84
Failed to read key     . rc:0x84
Command 0x1300 completed. inCount: 2 data:0x0Command 0x2 completed. inCount: 2 data:0x5Command 0x1 completed. inCount: 2 data:0x1001Command 0x16 completed. inCount: 2 data:0x40e0Command 0xa completed. inCount: 2 data:0x0Command 0xb completed. inCount: 2 data:0x0Command 0x12 completed. inCount: 2 data:0xffffCommand 0x13 completed. inCount: 2 data:0xffffCommand 0xf completed. inCount: 2 data:0x1270Command 0x10 completed. inCount: 2 data:0x12feSmartBattery: finished polling type 4
failed to lookup target storage class: 2failed to lookup target storage class: 2failed to lookup target storage class: 2Starting poll type 4
Restarting poll type 4
Command 0x1100 completed. inCount: 2 data:0x0Failed to read key     . rc:0x84
Failed to read key     . rc:0x84
Failed to read key     . rc:0x84
Failed to read key     . rc:0x84
Failed to read key     . rc:0x84
Command 0x1200 completed. inCount: 2 data:0x0Failed to read key     . rc:0x84
Failed to read key     . rc:0x84
Failed to read key     . rc:0x84
Failed to read key     . rc:0x84
Command 0x1300 completed. inCount: 2 data:0x0Command 0x2 completed. inCount: 2 data:0x5Command 0x1 completed. inCount: 2 data:0x1001Command 0x16 completed. inCount: 2 data:0x40e0Command 0xa completed. inCount: 2 data:0x0Command 0xb completed. inCount: 2 data:0x0Command 0x12 completed. inCount: 2 data:0xffffCommand 0x13 completed. inCount: 2 data:0xffffCommand 0xf completed. inCount: 2 data:0x1270Command 0x10 completed. inCount: 2 data:0x12feSmartBattery: finished polling type 4
+ IOAudioEngine[<ptr>]::newUserClient(0x<ptr>, <ptr>, 0x0, 0, <ptr>)
+ IOAudioEngineUserClient[<ptr>]::initWithAudioEngine(<ptr>, 0x<ptr>, <ptr>, 0x0, 0)
+- IOAudioEngineUserClient[<ptr>]::setOnline(0)
  ConnectionID:0xcc298fd3
- IOAudioEngineUserClient[<ptr>]::initWithAudioEngine(<ptr>, 0x<ptr>, <ptr>, 0x0, 0) returns 1
+- IOAudioEngineUserClient::withAudioEngine(<ptr>, 0x<ptr>, <ptr>, 0x0, 0) returns <ptr>
+ IOAudioEngine::addUserClientAction(<ptr>, <ptr>)
+- IOAudioEngine[<ptr>]::addUserClient(<ptr>) returns 0x0
- IOAudioEngine::addUserClientAction(<ptr>, <ptr>) returns 0x0
- IOAudioEngine[<ptr>]::newUserClient(0x<ptr>, <ptr>, 0x0, 0, <ptr>)
- IOAudioEngineUserClient[<ptr>]::registerFormatNotification(0x<ptr>, 0x100) returns 0x0
- IOAudioEngineUserClient::registerNotificationAction(<ptr>, <ptr>) returns 0x0
- IOAudioEngineUserClient[<ptr>]::registerNotificationPort(0x<ptr>, 0x0, 0x100) returns 0x0
+ IOAudioEngine[<ptr>]::newUserClient(0x<ptr>, <ptr>, 0x0, 0, <ptr>)
+ IOAudioEngineUserClient[<ptr>]::initWithAudioEngine(<ptr>, 0x<ptr>, <ptr>, 0x0, 0)
+- IOAudioEngineUserClient[<ptr>]::setOnline(0)
  ConnectionID:0x65e657a1
- IOAudioEngineUserClient[<ptr>]::initWithAudioEngine(<ptr>, 0x<ptr>, <ptr>, 0x0, 0) returns 1
+- IOAudioEngineUserClient::withAudioEngine(<ptr>, 0x<ptr>, <ptr>, 0x0, 0) returns <ptr>
+ IOAudioEngine::addUserClientAction(<ptr>, <ptr>)
+- IOAudioEngine[<ptr>]::addUserClient(<ptr>) returns 0x0
- IOAudioEngine::addUserClientAction(<ptr>, <ptr>) returns 0x0
- IOAudioEngine[<ptr>]::newUserClient(0x<ptr>, <ptr>, 0x0, 0, <ptr>)
- IOAudioEngineUserClient[<ptr>]::registerFormatNotification(0x<ptr>, 0x101) returns 0x0
- IOAudioEngineUserClient::registerNotificationAction(<ptr>, <ptr>) returns 0x0
- IOAudioEngineUserClient[<ptr>]::registerNotificationPort(0x<ptr>, 0x0, 0x101) returns 0x0
IOTimeSyncClockManager::addgPTPServices adding services
IOTimeSyncClockManager::addgPTPServices requesting matching
IOTimeSyncgPTPManager::init created and initing
IOTimeSyncgPTPManager::start starting
IOTimeSyncgPTPManager::start creating system domain
  IOTimeSyncDomain(0x15109fe02f4d0000): Started PTP Domain 0x15109fe02f4d0000
  IOTimeSyncMachNanoPort(0x15109fe02f4d0000): Battery Powered: true
  IOTimeSyncMachNanoPort(0x15109fe02f4d0000): Has Wired Ethernet Link: false
  IOTimeSyncMachNanoPort(0x15109fe02f4d0000): Has Ethernet HW Timestamps: false
  IOTimeSyncMachNanoPort(0x15109fe02f4d0000): Has WiFi HW Timestamps: false
  IOTimeSyncMachNanoPort(0x15109fe02f4d0000): External Power Connected: true
  IOTimeSyncMachNanoPort(0x15109fe02f4d0000): Device is battery powered
  IOTimeSyncDomain(0x15109fe02f4d0000): Set lock state to locking.
  IOTimeSyncMachNanoPort(0x15109fe02f4d0000): messagePriorityVector 250, 248, 33, 17258, 247, 0x15109fe02f4d0000, 0, 0x15109fe02f4d0000, 0, 0
  IOTimeSyncMachNanoPort(0x15109fe02f4d0000): Set role to Slave.
  IOTimeSyncDomain(0x15109fe02f4d0000): Set lock state to locked.
  IOTimeSyncDomain(0x15109fe02f4d0000): Set clock slave port to 0, grandmaster Identity 0x15109fe02f4d0000
Instantiated system domain 0x15109fe02f4d0000
IOTimeSyncgPTPManager::start registered service
IOTimeSyncClockManager::addgPTPServices adding services
IOTimeSyncClockManager::addgPTPServices adding services
IOTimeSyncClockManager::addgPTPServices adding services
Sandbox: 1 duplicate report for coreduetd deny(1) file-write-data /private/var/root/Library/Preferences/com.apple.coreduetd.plistfailed to lookup target storage class: 2failed to lookup target storage class: 2failed to lookup target storage class: 2failed to lookup target storage class: 2failed to lookup target storage class: 2failed to lookup target storage class: 2failed to lookup target storage class: 2failed to lookup target storage class: 2failed to lookup target storage class: 2failed to lookup target storage class: 2failed to lookup target storage class: 2failed to lookup target storage class: 2failed to lookup target storage class: 2failed to lookup target storage class: 2failed to lookup target storage class: 2failed to lookup target storage class: 2failed to lookup target storage class: 2failed to lookup target storage class: 2failed to lookup target storage class: 2failed to lookup target storage class: 2failed to lookup target storage class: 2syscall_extension_consume failed: 22syscall_extension_consume failed: 22syscall_extension_consume failed: 22syscall_extension_consume failed: 22failed to lookup target storage class: 2syscall_extension_consume failed: 22syscall_extension_consume failed: 22syscall_extension_consume failed: 22IOConsoleUsers: time(0) 0->0, lin 1, llk 0, 
IOConsoleUsers: gIOScreenLockState 1, hs 0, bs 0, now 0, sm 0x0
loginwindow is not entitled for IOHIDLibUserClient keyboard accessIOConsoleUsers: time(0) 0->0, lin 1, llk 0, 
IOConsoleUsers: gIOScreenLockState 1, hs 0, bs 0, now 0, sm 0x0
IOConsoleUsers: time(0) 0->0, lin 1, llk 0, 
IOConsoleUsers: gIOScreenLockState 1, hs 0, bs 0, now 0, sm 0x0
loginwindow is not entitled for IOHIDLibUserClient keyboard accessIOConsoleUsers: time(0) 0->0, lin 1, llk 0, 
IOConsoleUsers: gIOScreenLockState 1, hs 0, bs 0, now 0, sm 0x0
IOConsoleUsers: time(0) 0->0, lin 1, llk 0, 
IOConsoleUsers: gIOScreenLockState 1, hs 0, bs 0, now 0, sm 0x0
loginwindow is not entitled for IOHIDLibUserClient keyboard accessIOConsoleUsers: time(0) 0->0, lin 1, llk 0, 
IOConsoleUsers: gIOScreenLockState 1, hs 0, bs 0, now 0, sm 0x0
IOConsoleUsers: time(0) 0->0, lin 1, llk 0, 
IOConsoleUsers: gIOScreenLockState 1, hs 0, bs 0, now 0, sm 0x0
loginwindow is not entitled for IOHIDLibUserClient keyboard accessIOConsoleUsers: time(0) 0->0, lin 1, llk 0, 
IOConsoleUsers: gIOScreenLockState 1, hs 0, bs 0, now 0, sm 0x0
IOConsoleUsers: time(0) 0->0, lin 1, llk 0, 
IOConsoleUsers: gIOScreenLockState 1, hs 0, bs 0, now 0, sm 0x0
loginwindow is not entitled for IOHIDLibUserClient keyboard accessIOConsoleUsers: time(0) 0->0, lin 1, llk 0, 
IOConsoleUsers: gIOScreenLockState 1, hs 0, bs 0, now 0, sm 0x0
IOConsoleUsers: time(0) 0->0, lin 1, llk 0, 
IOConsoleUsers: gIOScreenLockState 1, hs 0, bs 0, now 0, sm 0x0
loginwindow is not entitled for IOHIDLibUserClient keyboard accessIOConsoleUsers: time(0) 0->0, lin 1, llk 0, 
IOConsoleUsers: gIOScreenLockState 1, hs 0, bs 0, now 0, sm 0x0
IOConsoleUsers: time(0) 0->0, lin 1, llk 0, 
IOConsoleUsers: gIOScreenLockState 1, hs 0, bs 0, now 0, sm 0x0
loginwindow is not entitled for IOHIDLibUserClient keyboard accessIOConsoleUsers: time(0) 0->0, lin 1, llk 0, 
IOConsoleUsers: gIOScreenLockState 1, hs 0, bs 0, now 0, sm 0x0
+ IOAudioEngineUserClient::externalMethod, selector=0x0,   arg0 0x0, arg1 0x10e395000, arg2 0x8010 arg3 0x66 
  scalarInputCount=0x4  structureInputSize 0x0, scalarOutputCount 0x0, structureOutputSize 0x0 
+ IOAudioEngineUserClient::registerBuffer64 0x0 0x10e395000 0x8010 0x66
+ IOAudioEngineUserClient::safeRegisterClientBuffer64 <ptr> 
+ IOAudioEngineUserClient[<ptr>]::registerClientBuffer64  (<ptr>[1], 0x10e395000, 0x8010, 0x66)
  null clientBufferSetList
  did not find clientBufferSetList for ID 0x66 
  clientBuffer->mAudioClientBuffer32.sourceBuffer before offset: <ptr>, offset size: 16
  clientBuffer->mAudioClientBuffer32.sourceBuffer after offset: <ptr>
  null clientBufferSetList
  did not find clientBufferSetList for ID 0x66 
  creating new IOAudioClientBufferSet 
  output 
  !isOnline 
- IOAudioEngineUserClient::registerClientBuffer64() result 0x0
- IOAudioEngineUserClient::safeRegisterClientBuffer64  returns 0x0
- IOAudioEngineUserClient::registerBuffer64 0x0 0x10e395000 0x8010 0x66 returns 0x0
- IOAudioEngineUserClient::externalMethod returns 0x0
+ IOAudioEngineUserClient::externalMethod, selector=0x3,   arg0 0x0, arg1 0x0, arg2 0x0 arg3 0x0 
  scalarInputCount=0x0  structureInputSize 0x0, scalarOutputCount 0x0, structureOutputSize 0x0 
+ IOAudioEngineUserClient[<ptr>]::startClient() - 0
  audioEngine && !isInactive(). State = 0 
  audioEngine->getState() != kIOAudioEnginePaused 
+- IOAudioEngineUserClient[<ptr>]::setOnline(1)
  !isOnline() setting online 
+ IOAudioEngine[<ptr>]::startClient(<ptr>)
+ IOAudioEngine[<ptr>]::incrementActiveUserClients() - 0
+ IOAudioEngine[<ptr>]::startAudioEngine(state = 0)
+ IOAudioDevice[<ptr>]::protectedCompletePowerStateChange() - current = 2 - pending = 2
- IOAudioDevice[<ptr>]::protectedCompletePowerStateChange() - current = 2 - pending = 2 returns 0x0
+ IOAudioDevice[<ptr>]::protectedCompletePowerStateChange() - current = 2 - pending = 2
- IOAudioDevice[<ptr>]::protectedCompletePowerStateChange() - current = 2 - pending = 2 returns 0x0
+ IOAudioDevice[<ptr>]::audioEngineStarting() - numRunningAudioEngines = 0
- IOAudioDevice[<ptr>]::audioEngineStarting() - numRunningAudioEngines = 1
+- IOAudioEngine[<ptr>]::resetStatusBuffer()
+-IOAudioEngine[<ptr>]::setState(0x1. oldState=0)
- IOAudioEngine[<ptr>]::getTimerInterval()
- IOAudioEngine[<ptr>]::startAudioEngine() returns 0x0
- IOAudioEngine[<ptr>]::incrementActiveUserClients() - 1 returns 0
- IOAudioEngine[<ptr>]::startClient(<ptr>) returns 0x0
  engine started 
  bufferSet <ptr> 
  output clientBuffer <ptr> 
+ IOAudioStream[<ptr>]::addClient(<ptr>)
- IOAudioStream[<ptr>]::addClient(<ptr>) returns 0x0
- IOAudioEngineUserClient[<ptr>]::startClient() - 1 returns 0x0
- IOAudioEngineUserClient::externalMethod returns 0x0
+ IOAudioControl[<ptr>]::setValue(int = 64)
+ IOAudioLevelControl::validateValue[<ptr>] (<ptr>)
  IOAudioLevelControl::validateValue[<ptr>] - newIntValue = 64, min = 0, max = 115
- IOAudioLevelControl::validateValue[<ptr>] (<ptr>) returns 0x0
  controlID: 2, coreAudioChannelID = 1 FRONT LEFT oldValue 0x46, newValue 0x40
- IOAudioControl[<ptr>]::setValue(int = 64) returns 0x0
+ IOAudioControl[<ptr>]::setValue(int = 64)
+ IOAudioLevelControl::validateValue[<ptr>] (<ptr>)
  IOAudioLevelControl::validateValue[<ptr>] - newIntValue = 64, min = 0, max = 115
- IOAudioLevelControl::validateValue[<ptr>] (<ptr>) returns 0x0
  controlID: 4, coreAudioChannelID = 2 FRONT RIGHT oldValue 0x46, newValue 0x40
- IOAudioControl[<ptr>]::setValue(int = 64) returns 0x0
+ IOAudioControl[<ptr>]::setValue(int = 64)
- IOAudioControl[<ptr>]::setValue(int = 64) returns 0x0
+ IOAudioControl[<ptr>]::setValue(int = 64)
- IOAudioControl[<ptr>]::setValue(int = 64) returns 0x0
+ IOAudioControl[<ptr>]::setValue(int = 0)
- IOAudioControl[<ptr>]::setValue(int = 0) returns 0x0
+ IOAudioControl[<ptr>]::setValue(int = 58)
+ IOAudioLevelControl::validateValue[<ptr>] (<ptr>)
  IOAudioLevelControl::validateValue[<ptr>] - newIntValue = 58, min = 0, max = 115
- IOAudioLevelControl::validateValue[<ptr>] (<ptr>) returns 0x0
  controlID: 2, coreAudioChannelID = 1 FRONT LEFT oldValue 0x40, newValue 0x3A
- IOAudioControl[<ptr>]::setValue(int = 58) returns 0x0
+ IOAudioControl[<ptr>]::setValue(int = 58)
+ IOAudioLevelControl::validateValue[<ptr>] (<ptr>)
  IOAudioLevelControl::validateValue[<ptr>] - newIntValue = 58, min = 0, max = 115
- IOAudioLevelControl::validateValue[<ptr>] (<ptr>) returns 0x0
  controlID: 4, coreAudioChannelID = 2 FRONT RIGHT oldValue 0x40, newValue 0x3A
- IOAudioControl[<ptr>]::setValue(int = 58) returns 0x0
+ IOAudioControl[<ptr>]::setValue(int = 58)
- IOAudioControl[<ptr>]::setValue(int = 58) returns 0x0
+ IOAudioControl[<ptr>]::setValue(int = 58)
- IOAudioControl[<ptr>]::setValue(int = 58) returns 0x0
+ IOAudioControl[<ptr>]::setValue(int = 0)
- IOAudioControl[<ptr>]::setValue(int = 0) returns 0x0
+ IOAudioControl[<ptr>]::setValue(int = 50)
+ IOAudioLevelControl::validateValue[<ptr>] (<ptr>)
  IOAudioLevelControl::validateValue[<ptr>] - newIntValue = 50, min = 0, max = 115
- IOAudioLevelControl::validateValue[<ptr>] (<ptr>) returns 0x0
  controlID: 2, coreAudioChannelID = 1 FRONT LEFT oldValue 0x3A, newValue 0x32
- IOAudioControl[<ptr>]::setValue(int = 50) returns 0x0
+ IOAudioControl[<ptr>]::setValue(int = 50)
+ IOAudioLevelControl::validateValue[<ptr>] (<ptr>)
  IOAudioLevelControl::validateValue[<ptr>] - newIntValue = 50, min = 0, max = 115
- IOAudioLevelControl::validateValue[<ptr>] (<ptr>) returns 0x0
  controlID: 4, coreAudioChannelID = 2 FRONT RIGHT oldValue 0x3A, newValue 0x32
- IOAudioControl[<ptr>]::setValue(int = 50) returns 0x0
+ IOAudioControl[<ptr>]::setValue(int = 50)
- IOAudioControl[<ptr>]::setValue(int = 50) returns 0x0
+ IOAudioControl[<ptr>]::setValue(int = 50)
- IOAudioControl[<ptr>]::setValue(int = 50) returns 0x0
+ IOAudioControl[<ptr>]::setValue(int = 0)
- IOAudioControl[<ptr>]::setValue(int = 0) returns 0x0
+ IOAudioControl[<ptr>]::setValue(int = 41)
+ IOAudioLevelControl::validateValue[<ptr>] (<ptr>)
  IOAudioLevelControl::validateValue[<ptr>] - newIntValue = 41, min = 0, max = 115
- IOAudioLevelControl::validateValue[<ptr>] (<ptr>) returns 0x0
  controlID: 2, coreAudioChannelID = 1 FRONT LEFT oldValue 0x32, newValue 0x29
- IOAudioControl[<ptr>]::setValue(int = 41) returns 0x0
+ IOAudioControl[<ptr>]::setValue(int = 41)
+ IOAudioLevelControl::validateValue[<ptr>] (<ptr>)
  IOAudioLevelControl::validateValue[<ptr>] - newIntValue = 41, min = 0, max = 115
- IOAudioLevelControl::validateValue[<ptr>] (<ptr>) returns 0x0
  controlID: 4, coreAudioChannelID = 2 FRONT RIGHT oldValue 0x32, newValue 0x29
- IOAudioControl[<ptr>]::setValue(int = 41) returns 0x0
+ IOAudioControl[<ptr>]::setValue(int = 41)
- IOAudioControl[<ptr>]::setValue(int = 41) returns 0x0
+ IOAudioControl[<ptr>]::setValue(int = 41)
- IOAudioControl[<ptr>]::setValue(int = 41) returns 0x0
+ IOAudioControl[<ptr>]::setValue(int = 0)
- IOAudioControl[<ptr>]::setValue(int = 0) returns 0x0
Starting poll type 4
Restarting poll type 4
Command 0x1100 completed. inCount: 2 data:0x0Failed to read key     . rc:0x84
Failed to read key     . rc:0x84
Failed to read key     . rc:0x84
Failed to read key     . rc:0x84
Failed to read key     . rc:0x84
Command 0x1200 completed. inCount: 2 data:0x0Failed to read key     . rc:0x84
Failed to read key     . rc:0x84
Failed to read key     . rc:0x84
Failed to read key     . rc:0x84
Command 0x1300 completed. inCount: 2 data:0x0Command 0x2 completed. inCount: 2 data:0x5Command 0x1 completed. inCount: 2 data:0x1001Command 0x16 completed. inCount: 2 data:0x40e0Command 0xa completed. inCount: 2 data:0x0Command 0xb completed. inCount: 2 data:0x0Command 0x12 completed. inCount: 2 data:0xffffCommand 0x13 completed. inCount: 2 data:0xffffCommand 0xf completed. inCount: 2 data:0x1270Command 0x10 completed. inCount: 2 data:0x12feSmartBattery: finished polling type 4
```

P.S.: It's macOS 10.14
P.P.S.: Sorry for bad english

---

#### UPD:

Trying to `kextunload` and `kextload` AppleHDA return to kernel panic on connecting headphones. Report:

```
    Anonymous UUID:       3D30EA4A-CFF7-DEC0-5F59-0264864BFB77

Sat Feb 29 23:38:15 2020

*** Panic Report ***
panic(cpu 0 caller 0xffffff802a8da1ed): Kernel trap at 0xffffff7fada03564, type 13=general protection, registers:
CR0: 0x000000008001003b, CR2: 0x00007fa0cf9ac050, CR3: 0x000000002e347000, CR4: 0x00000000001626e0
RAX: 0xffffff8041b5a900, RBX: 0xffffff8040e219c0, RCX: 0xc0ffeeba8da10596, RDX: 0x0000000001000000
RSP: 0xffffff812e7abb80, RBP: 0xffffff812e7abba0, RSI: 0x00000000000000d7, RDI: 0xffffff8041b5a900
R8:  0xffffff804d42f1b8, R9:  0xffffff803e21c380, R10: 0xffffff802b09d8e8, R11: 0x0000000000000001
R12: 0xffffff812e7abbf0, R13: 0xffffff7fada0ec4d, R14: 0x00000000e00002bc, R15: 0xffffff812e7abbf4
RFL: 0x0000000000010286, RIP: 0xffffff7fada03564, CS:  0x0000000000000008, SS:  0x0000000000000010
Fault CR2: 0x00007fa0cf9ac050, Error code: 0x0000000000000000, Fault CPU: 0x0, PL: 0, VF: 0

Backtrace (CPU 0), Frame : Return Address
0xffffff802a54c290 : 0xffffff802a7aeafd 
0xffffff802a54c2e0 : 0xffffff802a8e85a3 
0xffffff802a54c320 : 0xffffff802a8d9fca 
0xffffff802a54c390 : 0xffffff802a75bca0 
0xffffff802a54c3b0 : 0xffffff802a7ae517 
0xffffff802a54c4d0 : 0xffffff802a7ae363 
0xffffff802a54c540 : 0xffffff802a8da1ed 
0xffffff802a54c6b0 : 0xffffff802a75bca0 
0xffffff802a54c6d0 : 0xffffff7fada03564 
0xffffff812e7abba0 : 0xffffff7fada025f7 
0xffffff812e7abbd0 : 0xffffff7fada02237 
0xffffff812e7abc20 : 0xffffff7fada01d78 
0xffffff812e7abc60 : 0xffffff7fada01c15 
0xffffff812e7abca0 : 0xffffff7fada0331a 
0xffffff812e7abcc0 : 0xffffff7fada0259b 
0xffffff812e7abcf0 : 0xffffff7fada02374 
0xffffff812e7abd40 : 0xffffff7fada01d78 
0xffffff812e7abd80 : 0xffffff7fada01c15 
0xffffff812e7abdc0 : 0xffffff7fada01a7e 
0xffffff812e7abdf0 : 0xffffff7fada060c2 
0xffffff812e7abe10 : 0xffffff7fada0648e 
0xffffff812e7abe40 : 0xffffff802ae5546e 
0xffffff812e7abe80 : 0xffffff7fada05b2f 
0xffffff812e7abec0 : 0xffffff802a7eaf65 
0xffffff812e7abf40 : 0xffffff802a7eab15 
0xffffff812e7abfa0 : 0xffffff802a75b0ce 
      Kernel Extensions in backtrace:
         com.apple.driver.AppleMikeyDriver(282.10)[718D8878-FCDD-362F-BD81-A30176EAD73D]@0xffffff7fad9fe000->0xffffff7fada13fff
            dependency: com.apple.iokit.IOACPIFamily(1.4)[99A8A054-9F64-3FB8-BB1D-5973F8AB04A1]@0xffffff7fab747000
            dependency: com.apple.driver.AppleSMBusController(1.0.18d1)[358B8FF6-88DE-31BD-BF81-34E04A558829]@0xffffff7facecb000

BSD process name corresponding to current thread: kernel_task

Mac OS version:
18C54

Kernel version:
Darwin Kernel Version 18.2.0: Mon Nov 12 20:24:46 PST 2018; root:xnu-4903.231.4~2/RELEASE_X86_64
Kernel UUID: 56B30885-F9BA-30E8-AD1C-5D59EC243BA9
Kernel slide:     0x000000002a400000
Kernel text base: 0xffffff802a600000
__HIB  text base: 0xffffff802a500000
System model name: MacBookPro10,1 (Mac-C3EC7CD22292981F)

System uptime in nanoseconds: 1258205042545
last loaded kext at 719087707406: com.rugarciap.DisableTurboBoost   0.0.1 (addr 0xffffff7fadcbe000, size 12288)
last unloaded kext at 718750820930: com.rugarciap.DisableTurboBoost 0.0.1 (addr 0xffffff7fadcbe000, size 8192)
loaded kexts:
com.rugarciap.DisableTurboBoost 0.0.1
com.adguard.nfext   17
com.netease.nemu.kext.NemuDrv   15.2.97
com.frescologic.ProxyFramebuffer    1.1
us.palpant.NVDAGPUWakeHandler   1
com.orderedbytes.driver.ControllerMateFamily    4.6.0
com.frescologic.ProxyVideoCard  1.1
com.objective-see.lulu  1.2.3
com.valvesoftware.SteamInput    4357.73.42
com.orderedbytes.driver.CMUSBDevices    4.9.0
com.apple.filesystems.msdosfs   1.10
com.apple.driver.AudioAUUC  1.70
com.apple.fileutil  18.306.12
com.apple.filesystems.autofs    3.0
com.apple.driver.AppleHDAHardwareConfigDriver   282.10
com.apple.driver.AppleMikeyHIDDriver    131
com.apple.driver.AppleHDA   282.10
com.apple.driver.AGPM   110.23.46
com.apple.driver.X86PlatformShim    1.0.0
com.apple.driver.ApplePlatformEnabler   2.7.0d0
com.apple.driver.AppleMikeyDriver   282.10
com.apple.driver.AppleGraphicsDevicePolicy  3.28.4
com.apple.AGDCPluginDisplayMetrics  3.28.4
com.apple.driver.AppleHV    1
com.apple.driver.AppleUpstreamUserClient    3.6.5
com.apple.iokit.IOUserEthernet  1.0.1
com.apple.iokit.IOBluetoothSerialManager    6.0.9f2
com.apple.driver.AGDCBacklightControl   3.28.4
com.apple.driver.pmtelemetry    1
com.apple.Dont_Steal_Mac_OS_X   7.0.0
com.apple.driver.AppleIntelHD4000Graphics   12.0.4
com.apple.driver.AppleBacklight 170.12.11
com.apple.driver.eficheck   1
com.apple.driver.ACPI_SMC_PlatformPlugin    1.0.0
com.apple.driver.AppleSMCPDRC   1.0.0
com.apple.driver.AppleLPC   3.1
com.apple.driver.AppleSMCLMU    212
com.apple.driver.AppleMuxControl    3.28.4
com.apple.driver.AppleOSXWatchdog   1
com.apple.driver.AppleFIVRDriver    4.1.0
com.apple.driver.AppleIntelSlowAdaptiveClocking 4.0.0
com.apple.driver.AppleIntelFramebufferCapri 12.0.4
com.apple.driver.AppleMCCSControl   1.5.6
com.apple.driver.AppleThunderboltIP 3.1.2
com.apple.iokit.IOBluetoothUSBDFU   6.0.9f2
com.apple.driver.AppleUSBTCKeyEventDriver   254
com.apple.driver.AppleUSBTCButtons  254
com.apple.driver.AppleUSBTCKeyboard 254
com.apple.driver.AppleFileSystemDriver  3.0.1
com.apple.driver.AppleVirtIO    2.1.2
com.apple.filesystems.hfs.kext  407.200.4
com.apple.AppleFSCompression.AppleFSCompressionTypeDataless 1.0.0d1
com.apple.BootCache 40
com.apple.AppleFSCompression.AppleFSCompressionTypeZlib 1.0.0
com.apple.AppleSystemPolicy 1.0
com.apple.filesystems.apfs  945.230.6
com.apple.iokit.AppleBCM5701Ethernet    10.3.3
com.apple.driver.AppleSDXC  1.7.6
com.apple.driver.AirPort.Brcm4331   800.21.30
com.apple.private.KextAudit 1.0
com.apple.driver.AirPort.Brcm4360   1400.1.1
com.apple.driver.AppleAHCIPort  329.200.2
com.apple.driver.AppleSmartBatteryManager   161.0.0
com.apple.driver.AppleACPIButtons   6.1
com.apple.driver.AppleRTC   2.0
com.apple.driver.AppleHPET  1.8
com.apple.driver.AppleSMBIOS    2.1
com.apple.driver.AppleACPIEC    6.1
com.apple.driver.AppleAPIC  1.7
com.apple.driver.AppleIntelCPUPowerManagementClient 220.0.0
com.apple.nke.applicationfirewall   190
com.apple.security.TMSafetyNet  8
com.apple.driver.AppleIntelCPUPowerManagement   220.0.0
com.apple.kext.triggers 1.0
com.apple.driver.DspFuncLib 282.10
com.apple.kext.OSvKernDSPLib    527
com.apple.driver.AppleHDAController 282.10
com.apple.iokit.IOHDAFamily 282.10
com.apple.iokit.IOAVBFamily 710.1
com.apple.plugin.IOgPTPPlugin   700.7
com.apple.driver.AppleSSE   1.0
com.apple.driver.AppleBacklightExpert   1.1.0
com.apple.driver.IOPlatformPluginLegacy 1.0.0
com.apple.AppleGPUWrangler  3.28.4
com.apple.iokit.IONDRVSupport   530
com.apple.driver.AppleSMBusPCI  1.0.14d1
com.apple.driver.AppleGraphicsControl   3.28.4
com.apple.driver.X86PlatformPlugin  1.0.0
com.apple.driver.IOPlatformPluginFamily 6.0.0d8
com.apple.iokit.IOSlowAdaptiveClockingFamily    1.0.0
com.apple.iokit.IOAcceleratorFamily2    404.2.2
com.apple.iokit.IOSurface   255.1
com.apple.AppleGraphicsDeviceControl    3.28.4
com.apple.driver.AppleSMBusController   1.0.18d1
com.apple.iokit.IOGraphicsFamily    530.14
com.apple.driver.AppleThunderboltEDMSink    4.2.0
com.apple.driver.AppleThunderboltDPOutAdapter   5.5.8
com.apple.iokit.BroadcomBluetoothHostControllerUSBTransport 6.0.9f2
com.apple.iokit.IOBluetoothHostControllerUSBTransport   6.0.9f2
com.apple.iokit.IOBluetoothHostControllerTransport  6.0.9f2
com.apple.iokit.IOBluetoothFamily   6.0.9f2
com.apple.driver.AppleUSBMultitouch 263
com.apple.driver.AppleUSBAudio  315.6
com.apple.driver.usb.IOUSBHostHIDDevice 1.2
com.apple.iokit.IOAudioFamily   206.5
com.apple.vecLib.kext   1.2.0
com.apple.driver.usb.cdc    5.0.0
com.apple.driver.usb.networking 5.0.0
com.apple.driver.usb.AppleUSBHostCompositeDevice    1.2
com.apple.driver.usb.AppleUSBHub    1.2
com.apple.iokit.IOSerialFamily  11
com.apple.filesystems.hfs.encodings.kext    1
com.apple.driver.AppleThunderboltDPInAdapter    5.5.8
com.apple.driver.AppleThunderboltDPAdapterFamily    5.5.8
com.apple.driver.AppleThunderboltPCIDownAdapter 2.1.4
com.apple.driver.AppleXsanScheme    3
com.apple.iokit.IOAHCIBlockStorage  301.200.2
com.apple.driver.AppleThunderboltNHI    4.7.6
com.apple.iokit.IOThunderboltFamily 6.8.1
com.apple.iokit.IOEthernetAVBController 1.1.0
com.apple.iokit.IO80211Family   1200.12.2
com.apple.driver.mDNSOffloadUserClient  1.0.1b8
com.apple.driver.corecapture    1.0.4
com.apple.driver.AppleUSBMergeNub   900.4.2
com.apple.iokit.IOAHCIFamily    288
com.apple.driver.usb.AppleUSBEHCIPCI    1.2
com.apple.driver.usb.AppleUSBEHCI   1.2
com.apple.driver.usb.AppleUSBXHCIPCI    1.2
com.apple.driver.usb.AppleUSBXHCI   1.2
com.apple.driver.usb.AppleUSBHostPacketFilter   1.0
com.apple.iokit.IOUSBFamily 900.4.2
com.apple.driver.AppleUSBHostMergeProperties    1.2
com.apple.driver.AppleEFINVRAM  2.1
com.apple.driver.AppleEFIRuntime    2.1
com.apple.iokit.IOSMBusFamily   1.1
com.apple.iokit.IOHIDFamily 2.0.0
com.apple.security.quarantine   3
com.apple.security.sandbox  300.0
com.apple.kext.AppleMatch   1.0.0d1
com.apple.driver.DiskImages 493.0.0
com.apple.driver.AppleFDEKeyStore   28.30
com.apple.driver.AppleEffaceableStorage 1.0
com.apple.driver.AppleKeyStore  2
com.apple.driver.AppleUSBTDM    456.230.1
com.apple.driver.AppleMobileFileIntegrity   1.0.5
com.apple.kext.CoreTrust    1
com.apple.iokit.IOUSBMassStorageDriver  145.200.2
com.apple.iokit.IOSCSIBlockCommandsDevice   408.200.1
com.apple.iokit.IOSCSIArchitectureModelFamily   408.200.1
com.apple.iokit.IOStorageFamily 2.1
com.apple.driver.AppleCredentialManager 1.0
com.apple.driver.KernelRelayHost    1
com.apple.iokit.IOUSBHostFamily 1.2
com.apple.driver.usb.AppleUSBCommon 1.0
com.apple.driver.AppleBusPowerController    1.0
com.apple.driver.AppleSEPManager    1.0.1
com.apple.driver.IOSlaveProcessor   1
com.apple.iokit.IOReportFamily  47
com.apple.iokit.IOTimeSyncFamily    700.7
com.apple.iokit.IONetworkingFamily  3.4
com.apple.driver.AppleACPIPlatform  6.1
com.apple.driver.AppleSMC   3.1.9
com.apple.iokit.IOPCIFamily 2.9
com.apple.iokit.IOACPIFamily    1.4
com.apple.kec.pthread   1
com.apple.kec.Libm  1
com.apple.kec.corecrypto    1.0

EOF
```

Answer (score 1):

I suppose your problem is similar to those described in this URL: https://discussions.apple.com/thread/5541299

So this issue has somewhat a long history, and my MacBook Pro 2019 model with macOS 10.15.3 has the same problem. In most cases, the way to trigger it is to make Mac sleep with headphones plugged in.

To solve this issue temporarily, my suggestion is to plug out your headphones and plug it in again whenever you encounter the issue, it works for me each time.

If you want to handle this problem in a more serious way, this thread in AskDifferent community may help you:
[Mavericks: No sound after sleep](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/119177/mavericks-no-sound-after-sleep)

Please notice, this problem may have something to do with a hidden flaw in macOS which hasn't be repaired over several major OS versions (this is purely personal guess), so on the Internet I haven't found an authentic answer for the reason and solution of this issue. Still, you may give the different methods a try and see if one of these solve your problem.

Comment: Thanks, but no one way didn't help me..
Mac generally stuck in sleep mode with plugged headphones :\